# XSLT 1.0 Aggregate and select distinct key and sum

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm fairly new to XSLT, I've been trying to piece some of the other examples posted on this topic but I still can't quite get it right

This is an example of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
   <customer>
      <customerID>1234</customerID>
      <invoiceNo>5698</invoiceNo>
      <amount>1000.00</amount>
   </customer>
   <customer>
      <customerID>7755</customerID>
      <invoiceNo>7864</invoiceNo>
      <amount>1500.00</amount>
   </customer>
   <customer>
      <customerID>1234</customerID>
      <invoiceNo>3697</invoiceNo>
      <amount>800.00</amount>
   </customer>
</customers>
```

The result I'm looking for is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <customerID>1234</customerID>
        <totalAmount>1800</totalAmount>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customerID>7755</customerID>
        <totalAmount>1500</totalAmount>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

This is my current XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="kCustomer" match="customer" use="customerID" />

<xsl:template match="customers">
<customers>
<xsl:apply-templates select="customer[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kCustomer',customerID[1])]"/>
</customers>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="customer" >
<customer>
<xsl:for-each select="key('kCustomer', customerID)">
<customerID><xsl:value-of select="key('kCustomer',customerID)/customerID"/></customerID>
<totalAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kCustomer', customerID)/amount)" /></totalAmount>
</xsl:for-each>
</customer>
            
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

It's giving me the SUM value but it's printing duplicates based on the numbers of invoices.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <customerID>1234</customerID>
        <totalAmount>1800</totalAmount>
        <customerID>1234</customerID>
        <totalAmount>1800</totalAmount>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customerID>7755</customerID>
        <totalAmount>1500</totalAmount>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: The XSLT you posted throws an error because a closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:template match="customer" >
<customer>
<xsl:for-each select="key('kCustomer', customerID)">
<customerID><xsl:value-of select="key('kCustomer',customerID)/customerID"/></customerID>
<totalAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kCustomer', customerID)/amount)" /></totalAmount>
</xsl:for-each>
</customer>
            
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
<customer>
<xsl:copy-of select="customerID"/>
<totalAmount><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kCustomer', customerID)/amount)" /></totalAmount>
</customer>
</xsl:template>
```

---

For better understanding, read the original article: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

---

P.S. Indentation improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a grouping query: a search for "XSLT grouping" will give you lots of information. Grouping becomes very easy in XSLT 2.0 using the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction, but in 1.0 you need to use an obscure workaround called "Muenchian grouping" (after its inventor, Steve Muench) - @michael.hor257k has shown you an example using this approach.

But it's best to move to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 if you can - lots of things become easier.

Comment: Muenchian grouping is the *de facto* standard method of grouping in XSLT 1.0. I don't think it can be called "obscure".

Comment: Thanks, but I can't. I'm using an integration tool, we're not the vendor and it only supports 1.0 at the moment. Most of the time its JSON/Liquid but I have to stand up some examples and I was struggling to make sense of some of the examples.

Comment: It's obscure in the sense that very few people would be able come up with the code unless they'd already encountered the pattern; and in the sense that even when you see the code, it's far from obvious to most people how or why it works.